# Can happiness be purely a state of mind?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, happiness, emotions, philosophy-of-psychology

Are there any mainstream philosophers (I assume it is meaningful to define such a subset of philosophers!) who argue that happiness can be a self-induced frame of mind? To put the question another way, can a state of happiness be attained by self-reflection alone, regardless of one's circumstances?

Comment: It would depend on how you define "happiness". If "happiness" is absence of suffering, then Buddhism (there are many, many forms!) would say that absence of suffering can be reached by cultivating the right mind.

Comment: I was thinking about this. It's typical to allow some people to deceive us when "Honesty would lead to nausea and suicide. But now there is a counterforce against our honesty that helps us to avoid such consequences: art as the good will to appearance". so maybe on the surface? So not being tricked by moralists and not due to the horrors of what is, but allowing yourself to be happy despite everyone's lies

Comment: I'm not a mainstream philosopher.

Comment: This was (and is) the general [take on happiness by Stoics](https://stoicquotes.com/quotes-on-control/#stoic_quotes_about_control_and_happiness). "*Some things are within our power, while others are not. Within our power are opinion, motivation, desire, aversion, and, in a word, whatever is of our own doing; not within our power are our body, our property, reputation, office, and, in a word, whatever is not of our own doing... There is only one way to happiness and that is to cease worrying about things that are not within our power,*" Epictetus.

Comment: I think this question could be improved by putting bounds on "circumstances" to account for the fact that the body is a chemistry machine and the brain is part of the body; and by replacing "self-reflection" with "internal mental processes" or something of that sort, to allow for the possibility of reflection on something other than the self and meditative practices that seek a state of no-self.

Comment: @Conifold that should be an answer.

Comment: "***can*** a state of happiness be attained by self-reflection alone, regardless of one's circumstances?"  Of course it *can*.

Comment: "mainstream" philosophers. :) I don't think I have witnessed any field which has less propensity for any kind of mainstream whatsoever. I would have an answer about the "happiness" part of the question, but not about the part about mainstream philosophers...

Comment: (Pauses video game.) What was that? Um... (Returns to video game.)

Comment: happyness is the state of mind&soul&body where all your focus from this world is of of your atention and you are doing something that fullfills you. it doesnt have to be neyther extatic nor joyfull , but peacefull.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I'd say that fits Buddhism, where not happiness in the sense of getting what you want, but Bliss rooted in understanding the true nature of things, is the fruit of meditation and cultivating the Eightfold Path as part of acknowledging the Four Noble Truths.

Awakening, or Unshakeable Liberation, is described as arriving suddenly, all at once, and irrevocably (with some disagreements by denomination). It's not strictly 'self induced', except for someone who is a Buddha with the power to do this without hearing the teaching. In a realm with the teaching, Boddhisattvas or Arahants are those who fully realise the teaching, and attain the state of ceasing to cause suffering, and able to access the state of Nirvana or Bliss.

Comment: Depends on what you call `self`. This is also true for Yoga. That happiness depending on external circumstances is simply impossible unless in the short term. One can also interpret Christianity in a similar way. And it is also logical that external circumstances can't be the ultimate cause of happiness because many rich and successful people are utterly unhappy.

Answer (score 8):

It would depend on how you define "happiness". If "happiness" is "absence of suffering", then Buddhism (there are many, many forms!) would generally say that cultivating the right mind could lead to the cessation of suffering. The [Dhammapada](https://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/scrndhamma.pdf), which is a reference text in some forms of Buddhism, opens with these lines (re-reading this today, I'm realizing there are serious philosophical commitments here):

> All experience is preceded by mind,
> Led by mind,
> Made by mind,
> Speak or act with a corrupted mind,
> And suffering follows
> As the wagon wheel follows the hoof of the ox.

> All experience is preceded by mind,
> Led by mind,
> Made by mind,
> Speak or act with a peaceful mind,
> And happiness follows
> Like a never departing shadow.

([Translation by Gil Fronsdal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590303806))

Comment: "Mind precedes all mental states. Mind is their chief; they are all mind-wrought."

Answer (score 4):

Happiness as a self-induced state of mind regardless of circumstance is the end goal of the Buddhist path as stated repeatedly in the Pali Suttas of Buddhism. The [simile of the saw](https://suttacentral.net/mn21/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) states this in no uncertain terms:

> Even if low-down bandits were to sever you limb from limb with a
> two-handled saw, anyone who had a malevolent thought on that account
> would not be following my instructions. (MN 21)

However, such happiness requires the conviction that better things are in reach regardless of the present circumstance. If pain and anguish is all you know, it's hard to accept that there might be a better world out there.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Ancient Greek philosophers and modern [positive psychologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_psychology) believe so, the latter relying on the empirical evidence. If one broadens philosophy to philosophy of psychology, then [Martin Seligman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Seligman), who helped realign psychology with one of it's three original aims besides dealing with mental illness, that of bringing well-being to a person's life, has written at least two books on the matter, though there are entire textbooks written on the topic:

> Positive psychology focuses on eudaimonia, an Ancient Greek term for "the good life" and the concept for reflection on the factors that contribute the most to a well-lived and fulfilling life. Positive psychologists often use the terms subjective well-being and happiness interchangeably.

There are a number of philosophical terms from Ancient Greek such as [eudaimonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia), [ataraxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataraxia), and [hedone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedone) are of interest to positive psychologists, who as a principle believe that human beings can choose to be happy. Among evidence-based traditional psychological thinking, such as [CBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy), there are ways to eliminate suffering from life, such exploring [cognitive distortions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion) and [cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias) that lead to poor self-image and choices with undesirable consequences. Lastly, the humanist school as practiced by Frankl, May, Rodgers, Maslow and others believes that reflection and therapy can lead to happiness. Maslow is perhaps the most famous for his [hierarchy of needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs) which examines how to reach [self-actualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization). You ask:

> To put the question another way, can a state of happiness be attained by self-reflection alone, regardless of one's circumstances?

So, the case for it seems very cogent to claim that many contemporary philosophers of psychology, those of the last 80 years who have helped pioneer modern psychological practice believe that talk therapy, a form of reflection, absolutely can alter a state of the mind in the direction of happiness by reflection. This thinking isn't too distant from late [Ludwig Wittgenstein (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/) who believed that philosophy was a therapy devoted to curing one of one's misconceptions and getting closer to the truth:

> In the Preface to PI, Wittgenstein states that his new thoughts would be better understood by contrast with and against the background of his old thoughts, those in the Tractatus; and indeed, most of Part I of PI is essentially questioning. Its new insights can be understood as primarily exposing fallacies in the traditional way of thinking about language, truth, thought, intentionality, and, perhaps mainly, philosophy. In this sense, it is conceived of as a therapeutic work, viewing philosophy itself as therapy.